# Price before/above add-to-cart button

Tags: commerce

Have struggled with this for a couple of days and find no easy solution (TWIG?)
Drupal commerce 2.X (D8)

I need to move the price before/above add-to-cart button
Like this:
Color:
Red
Size:
Medium
Price:
$ 49,00

Add to cart

I need to do this because the price of the product changes when you choose variation.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2928139) for this. It is an old issue, still unsolved. May be it draws attention when you comment there. It is a form of voting for its importance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed. a major frustration and it just makes no sense the way it is. i asked this same question a year ago and it has still not been solved. if you solve it please put the solution here.

meantime, you can use jquery appendTo() to solve it in a very ugly way. the price will initially load above the attributes and then jump down to the correct place above the cart button. it is not a pretty site but at least it works.

Comment: Its a shame that after so many years this isn't recognised as bug.